# Exception has occurred: InvalidArgumentError You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype string and shape [1]

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, placeholder

I just write those parts of my code in which I get an error which I mention for the placeholder. I comment below in front of the code where I get that error

```
# Read the shape information and compressed string from the binary file. 
string_ll= tf.placeholder(tf.string, [1])
string_lh= tf.placeholder(tf.string, [1])
string_hl= tf.placeholder(tf.string, [1])
string_hh= tf.placeholder(tf.string, [1])

x_ll_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])
x_lh_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])
x_hl_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])
x_hh_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])

y_ll_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])
y_lh_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])
y_hl_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])
y_hh_shape = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [2])

with open((args.input_file+'ll'), "rb") as f:
 packed_ll = tfc.PackedTensors(f.read())
with open((args.input_file+'lh'), "rb") as f:
 packed_lh = tfc.PackedTensors(f.read())
with open((args.input_file+'hl'), "rb") as f:
 packed_hl = tfc.PackedTensors(f.read())
with open((args.input_file+'hh'), "rb") as f:
packed_hh = tfc.PackedTensors(f.read()) 

tensors_ll = [string_ll,x_ll_shape, y_ll_shape]
tensors_lh = [string_lh,x_lh_shape, y_lh_shape]
tensors_hl = [string_hl,x_hl_shape, y_hl_shape]
tensors_hh = [string_hh,x_hh_shape, y_hh_shape]

arrays_ll = packed_ll.unpack(tensors_ll)
arrays_lh = packed_lh.unpack(tensors_lh)
arrays_hl = packed_hl.unpack(tensors_hl)
arrays_hh = packed_hh.unpack(tensors_hh)

# Instantiate model.
prediction=Prediction(args.num_filters)
encoder = Encoder(args.num_filters)
decoder = Decoder(args.num_filters)
entropy_bottleneck = tfc.EntropyBottleneck(dtype=tf.float32)

y_ll_shape=tf.concat([y_ll_shape,[args.num_filters]],axis=0)
y_lh_shape=tf.concat([y_lh_shape,[args.num_filters]],axis=0)
y_hl_shape=tf.concat([y_hl_shape,[args.num_filters]],axis=0)
y_hh_shape=tf.concat([y_hh_shape,[args.num_filters]],axis=0)

y_ll_hat = entropy_bottleneck.decompress(string_ll,y_ll_shape,channels=args.num_filters)
y_lh_hat = entropy_bottleneck.decompress(string_lh,y_lh_shape,channels=args.num_filters)
y_hl_hat = entropy_bottleneck.decompress(string_hl,y_hl_shape,channels=args.num_filters)
y_hh_hat = entropy_bottleneck.decompress(string_hh,y_hh_shape,channels=args.num_filters)

x_ll_hat = decoder(y_ll_hat)
x_lh_hat = decoder(y_lh_hat)
x_hl_hat = decoder(y_hl_hat)
x_hh_hat = decoder(y_hh_hat)

p_ff_hat=prediction(x_ll_hat)

x_lh_hat= x_lh_hat+p_ff_hat #here when i do the operation without add of p_ff_hat variable      
x_hl_hat= x_hl_hat+p_ff_hat #it look fine but in addition of the variable these line of code 
x_hh_hat= x_hh_hat+p_ff_hat  #execute but the error i got in last session. i mention 

# Remove batch dimension, and crop away any extraneous padding on the bottom
x_ll_hat = x_ll_hat[0, :x_ll_shape[0], :x_ll_shape[1], :]
x_lh_hat = x_lh_hat[0, :x_lh_shape[0], :x_lh_shape[1], :]
x_hl_hat = x_hl_hat[0, :x_hl_shape[0], :x_hl_shape[1], :]
x_hh_hat = x_hh_hat[0, :x_hh_shape[0], :x_hh_shape[1], :]
 

op_ll = write_png(args.output_file+'ll', x_ll_hat)
op_lh = write_png(args.output_file+'lh', x_lh_hat)
op_hl = write_png(args.output_file+'hl', x_hl_hat)
op_hh = write_png(args.output_file+'hh', x_hh_hat)

# Load the latest model checkpoint, and perform the above actions.
with tf.Session() as sess:
   latest = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir=args.checkpoint_dir)
   tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, save_path=latest)

   sess.run(op_ll, feed_dict=dict(zip(tensors_ll, arrays_ll)))

   sess.run(op_lh, feed_dict=dict(zip(tensors_lh, arrays_lh))) #here I got the error
   sess.run(op_hl, feed_dict=dict(zip(tensors_hl, arrays_hl)))
   sess.run(op_hh, feed_dict=dict(zip(tensors_hh, arrays_hh)))
```

The error I get is the following:
I am stuck here since from two weeks your help will be really appreciated and mean a lot to me. Thank you

> 2 root error(s) found.
> (0) Invalid argument:You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype string and shape [1][[node Placeholder (defined at home/image902/Desktop/compression-master/models/wavelet.py:783) ]]
> (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype string and shape [1] [[node Placeholder (defined at home/image902/Desktop/compression-master/models/wavelet.py:783) ]]
> [[entropy_bottleneck_1/decompress/TensorArray_1/_217]]
> 0 successful operations.
> 0 derived errors ignored.

> Original stack trace for 'Placeholder':
> File "usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "**main**", mod_spec)
> File "usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "home/image902/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python 2020.9.114305/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/**main**.py", line 45, in 
> cli.main()
> File "home/image902/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.9.114305/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
> run()
> File "home/image902/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.9.114305/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 267, in run_file
> runpy.run_path(options.target,run_name=compat.force_str("**main**"))
> File "usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
> File "usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
> File "usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)
> File "home/image902/Desktop/compression-master/models/wavelet.py", line 1046, in 
> main(args)
> File "home/image902/Desktop/compression-master/models/wavelet.py", line 991, in main
> decompress(args)
> File "home/image902/Desktop/compression-master/models/wavelet.py", line 783, in decompress

Comment: It would be better if you described your code in more details, the variable names are really confusing, it seems tensor `op_lh` is of incorrect type, but why I might only guess, you should check if `write_png` run as expected

Comment: I provide all of my code. here each step I repeat just only for four frequency subband of wavelets transform. that's why the code seems a little confusing.